# Good Solution for code distribution

Tags: matlab, software-distribution

I'm in the situation of creating program specific code (for several -different- programs) that needs to be distributed in plain text. As of now and the middle-future, code is only edited by me, but used by many people, who use Windows and are non-developers.

I would like to keep a "repository" that each of the computers automatically acccess, so I can make modifications to the code and they can use it straight up (the solutions would show up in their local, program specific folder (think MatLab or other scientific scriptable software).

Needless to say something like git would be totally overblown and a mess to use for them. Version control and conscious update is a desired feature, though.

Quick and dirty solution that I can think of is to share a dropbox folder, and make a windows automation task that copies that folder to their local program specific folder.

Are there any pitfalls in this solution ?  Is there any other system you can recommend ?

Comment: What's wrong with using github and then writing in the logic to check for updates directly into the code? All major git repository hosting services (Gitlab, github, etc.) have a public API that you can use to check for updates. The benefit here is that it is platform agnostic.

Comment: I think its overkill, so I asked for a less potent solution (since users don't edit the code, and they have a user mindset), but thanks for pointing to write the self-update in the code (and having into account platform "agnosticity"). I would have to distribute a specific git installation, with the location of different folders and such, right ?

Comment: The beauty is that you wouldn't have to distribute **any** git installation as the web API is accessible via  HTTP requests (which is built into *any* programming language) (in MATLAB this would be `urlwrite`)

Comment: When asking for a better solution, what are potential disadvantages of github?

Comment: What about using a shared network drive? Edit: okay, no version control obviously.

Comment: Questions of this nature are likely better suited for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Suever hit the nail. If I don't have to distribute any git installation, then it isn't overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github (or any git host) is not as overkill as you'd think since you can rely on the [web API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) rather than requiring all of your users to install git on their local machine. The ability to query this web API is available in most languages as you only need the ability to make an HTTP request and process a JSON response.

Below is an example of a very simple updater in MATLAB that relies upon Github's [release feature](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/). (This could be easily modified to compare against `master`)

```
function yourProgram(doUpdate)
    if exist('doUpdate', 'var') && doUpdate
        update();
    end

    % Do the actual work
end

function update()
    disp('Checking for update')

    % Information about this project
    thisVersion = 'v1.0';
    gitproject = 'cladelpino/project';

    root = ['https://api.github.com/repos/', gitproject];

    % Get the latest release from github
    release = webread([root, '/releases/latest']);

    if ~strcmp(release.tag_name, thisVersion)
        disp('New Version Found')

        % Get the current filename
        thisfile = [mfilename, '.m'];

        url = [root, '/contents/', thisfile];
        fileinfo = webread(url, 'ref', release.tag_name);

        % Download the new version to the current file
        websave(mfilename('fullpath'), fileinfo.download_url);
        disp('New Version downloaded')
    else
        disp('Everything is up to date!');
    end
end
```

This example assumes that you're only updating this single file. Modifications would have to be made to handle an entire project, but it's fairly straightforward given the example.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't aware this was possible! thanks